# Pack and unpack multiple signed integer number to single unsigned integer in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am trying to encode 3 signed integers into 3 - 32 bits slots using bit shifting, which works fine but not with negative numbers. This could be a simple problem in C++ with the negative conversion but I never work on C++ or know any good resources to follow.

Could anyone please shed light of how to deal with a negative number in this situation?

Really appreciate it.

```
    function encodeNumbers(int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) public pure returns(uint256 encoded) {

        encoded |= uint(a) << 64;

        encoded |= uint(b) << 32;

        encoded |= uint(c);

        return encoded;
    }
    
    function decodeNumber(uint256 encoded) public pure returns (int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) {

        a = int(encoded) >> 64;

        b = (int(encoded) << 192) >> 224;

        c = (int(encoded) << 224) >> 224;
    }
```

Comment: The problem you have is that negative numbers intXX have their sign extended to the full bit length. If you want to combine several of them you have to mask out those bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use casting to/from uint32/int32 to cut the unneeded bits.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

contract Untitled {
    
    event Numbers(int256 i, int256 j, int256 k);
    
    function foo() public returns (uint256) {
        int256 x = -123;
        int256 y = 8545;
        int256 z = -42;
        
        uint256 encoded = encodeNumbers(x, y, z);
        (int256 r, int256 s, int256 t) = decodeNumber(encoded);
        emit Numbers(r, s, t);
        
        return encoded;
    }
    
    function encodeNumbers(int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) public pure returns(uint256 encoded) {
        encoded |= uint256(uint32(int32(a))) << 64;
        encoded |= uint256(uint32(int32(b))) << 32;
        encoded |= uint256(uint32(int32(c)));

        return encoded;
    }
    
    function decodeNumber(uint256 encoded) public pure returns (int256 a, int256 b, int256 c) {
        a = int256(int32(uint32(encoded >> 64)));
        b = int256(int32(uint32(encoded >> 32)));
        c = int256(int32(uint32(encoded)));
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: Hi Ismael, thank you so much for your input. It's a decent solution.